# Python convert multiple column values into a single column

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, transpose

In Python how to convert the following table structure into rows

```
ID   Manager1    Manager2    Manager3
1    S394[1]       G490[2]     3004[3]
2    3905[1]       4003[2]     5003[3]
```

**Expected Output**

```
    ID   Manager
    1    S394[1]
    1    G490[2]
    1    3004[3]
    2    3905[1] 
    2    4003[2] 
    2    5003[3]
```

I tried using `transpose()` and `pivot()`. Both options did not work

```
df.pivot(index='SOEID',columns=['Manager1','Manager2','Manager3'])
```

I also tried pd.melt() I get an error saying index has only 1 level not 2.

```
df.melt(id_vars='SOEID', var_name=['Manager1','Manager2','Manager3'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lreshape` too:

```
pd.lreshape(df, {'Manager': ['Manager1', 'Manager2','Manager3']}).sort_values('ID')
```

Ouput:

```
   ID  Manager
0   1  S394[1]
2   1  G490[2]
4   1  3004[3]
1   2  3905[1]
3   2  4003[2]
5   2  5003[3]
```

**Note**: `lreshape` is currently undocumented, and it's possible [it might be removed](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15003#issuecomment-324625271).

Answer (score 1):

Problem is you need `value_vars` for list of columns names in [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html):

```
df1 = (df.melt(id_vars='ID', 
             value_vars=['Manager1','Manager2','Manager3'], 
             value_name='Manager', 
             var_name='tmp').drop('tmp', axis=1).sort_values('ID'))
 

print (df1)
   ID  Manager
0   1  S394[1]
2   1  G490[2]
4   1  3004[3]
1   2  3905[1]
3   2  4003[2]
5   2  5003[3]
```

Alternative solution with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df2 = (df.set_index('ID')[['Manager1','Manager2','Manager3']]
         .stack()
         .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
         .reset_index(name='Manager'))

print (df2)
   ID  Manager
0   1  S394[1]
1   1  G490[2]
2   1  3004[3]
3   2  3905[1]
4   2  4003[2]
5   2  5003[3]
```